# gulp-uncss removes class which is added using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, gulp-uncss

My gulp configuration for gulp-uncss is

```
gulp.task('uncssme', function () {

return gulp.src('src/css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(uncss({
        html: ['src/**/*.html']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

Using uncss removes 'newClass' selector from final css files because that class in not directly used in .html file but added dynamically through js.

```
document.getElementById('good').className += ' newClass';
```

EDIT:
I am already using /* uncss:ignore */ to make it work but this doesn't make sense to add this comment everytime for a class present in .js but not in .html

Comment: @Guy who downvoted this question, get some sense. If you don't have anything to help to improve question by adding comments, don't downvote blindly.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I can kind of see why they did.  Did you [read the documentation](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss#usage-examples), specifically the snippet below that that illustrates "[ignoring] specific selectors"?

Comment: I am already following that [ignoring] stuff using /* uncss:ignore */. And they have totally poor issue tracking response. Also, putting ignore for every newly added selector is unnecessary and burden than easing the task. I would rather go for other plugin. What you think? Any better plugin, please suggest.

Comment: I wish I could, but I've never tried anything of this nature.  It would make sense that any classes that are added via js would need to be whitelisted.  They could have the task scan js files too, but that doesn't take into account things like `$(this).addClass('brand-' + userColor)` or whatever.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking if some js parse synched with uncss could make it work. But anyways, thanks. Strange thing is I am not able to find the similar query anywhere else on net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, you can prefix every class using only in js widh `is-` and add ignore option with a regex in gulp task.

```
gulp.task('uncssme', function () {

return gulp.src('src/css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(uncss({
        html: ['src/**/*.html'],
        ignore: [^\.is-.*]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks. I still am having some problem with adding purifyjs as was suggested in previous answer. But your solution also seems a good deal as I can prefix something like jsa(js added) to the classes add by js only.

Comment: I just tried regex but it didn't work, pretty strange but hard coding literal like ignore: ['.is-newClass'] worked :P

Comment: The regex is to be used like ignore: [^\.is-.*] , i.e., without quotes inside array. Then it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Uncss and only way to get this working is using ignore comments which is not something i would consider being great solution.

I would suggest you try purifycss plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-purifycss/).
You can set both html and js files and then the css is uncss-ed or purify-ed and that was what i was looking for when i had your problem.

Comment: Aah thanks. I knew just the name but totally forgot to explore it. Right now, while using it, I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined. But I'll look into it. :)

Comment: Ok, that error was resolved but it didn't seem to run even simple case, which is to remove a class selector which is not used anywhere. If this didn't work, I can't check further whether it is keeping class added through js.

Comment: My gulp is: gulp.task('purifycss', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/bundle/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(purify(['src/bundle/js/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.html']))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/bundle/css'))
});

Comment: here is mine, working 100% and used in production: 
gulp.task('compile:css', ['clear:dist'], function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/static/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(purify(['./src/static/js/*.js', './src/*.html']))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 10 versions', 'IE 7']
        }))
        .pipe(csscomb())
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/css/'))
});

Comment: After you gave config, I experimented with my and your configs. And here are my observations. STRANGE THINGS. If I've 2 selectors in css '.js-newClass' and '.newClass1' and only former is being added through js. So purifycss still keeps '.newClass1' because of string matching 'newClass' in both which is why my config didn't look like it worked. More cases, if it was '.newClassA' then it will remove this because it considers 'newClass' and 'newClass(number)' same. Also '.js-newClass-hello' and '.newClass1' were treated same. So it kept both even though '.newClass1' wasn't used anywhere.

Comment: For more details, you can refer to issue raised at https://github.com/purifycss/gulp-purifycss/issues/16